# Update one object in collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have object and collection in this object.

```
myObject.myCollection.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault() = newMyCollection;
```

Unfortunately this didn't works

If I change single element, then work. For example:

```
myObject.myCollection.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault().Id = newMyCollection.Id;
```

How to update all of object? Thanks for any help

I can do something like this:

```
myObject.myCollection.Remove(objectOfMyCollection);
myObject.MyCollection.Add(myNewCollection);
```

But: If my `objectOfMyCollection` is firstly, then my new object be last.

Comment: The Q in Linq is for "query" not "update".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var customListItem2 = myObject.myCollection.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
var index = myObject.myCollection.IndexOf(customListItem2);

if(index != -1)
    myObject.myCollection[index] = newCustomListItem;
```

Comment: Hmm. My myObject is still old data. 

if(index != -1)
    myObject.myCollection[index] = newCustomListItem;

If I have to add .Name = newCustomListItem.Name - then work. Any idea?

Comment: Are you working with linq to object or linq to entity (entity framework)? This code works with linq to objects only

Comment: Yes, exactly : ). Okey, how to do?

Comment: You can get the same with entity framework by using Detach and Attach entity

Comment: Some another way?

Comment: I think no. The steps is that detach the old entity, attach the new one and mark its state to Modified before call savechanges

Comment: Hmm. Another. Before save it I check in debugger. myObject is still old data after  myObject.myCollection[index] = newCustomListItem;

Comment: i said that the above code only work with linq to object. you have to utilize detach and attach to get working with entity framework. refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can just query for a list and iterate over that:

```
foreach (var obj in myObject.myCollection.Where(a => a.Id == Id).ToList()) {
    obj.Id = newMyCollection.Id;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want responsive :) I can use remove and add but this change index if element is in for example firstly

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: Some element in my database might change. I dont have to change this code if I again change database

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, could you edit your question and add a example scenario?

Comment: Look. Object is my entity from database. myCollection have many elements: for example: name, url, title. Sometimes it may necessary to add another element fe: description. Then I have to change my loop and and next element obj.Description = newMyCollection.Description.

Comment: Unfortunately implementing that is quite difficult. One way to do it is by using reflection to look up all the fields of your `newMyCollection` and then setting all the values of your `obj`. Sadly I don't have enough experience with reflection to give you a code example, but take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would have to replace the underlying references in your list which isn't possible with LINQ (which is designed for *querying*, not *updating* objects).

To do this with a list use an old-school `for`-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    if(myList[i].Id == Id) 
    {
        myList[i] = newElement;
        break;
    }
}
```

Using a `for`- instead of a `foreach` is necessary here because you re-reference the instances in your list which is not possible using the latter.

Another approach was to create a temporary copy of your list, get the matching element there and it´s index in the list and replace the element at that index in the original list:

```
var tmp = myList;

foreach(var elem in tmp)
{
    if(elem.Id == Id) 
    {
        var index = myList.IndexOf(x => x.Id == Id);
        myList[index] = newElement;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change only first index you can do something like this:

```
myObject.myCollection.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault(a => { a.Id = newMyCollection.Id; return true; });
```

Which in plain English does :

`- From myCollection get items Where item's Id is equal to Id`

`- From selected values get FirstItem and set it's Id to the new one`

`- Do not check the rest`

Or even make it simplier :

```
myObject.myCollection.FirstOrDefault(a => { if(a.Id == Id) { a.Id = newMyCollection.Id; return true; } return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate SQL `UPDATE with JOIN` and update one or more objects, you can use LINQ as below, this time using `CollectionBase`-derived objects. But you can use `List<T>`, etc

```
(from Type1 o1 in collection1
 join Type2 o2 in collection2 on o1.Id equals o2.RelatedId
 select new { O1 = o1, O2 = o2 }).
 Count(item => (item.O1.SomeProperty = item.O2.SomeOtherProperty) == null);
```

A little hacky but it acts similar to SQL and does not mutate collections. YeA, it creates light objects that only hold reference to original collection items.